# Why is Rubocop taking 30 seconds to to start analyzing files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, performance, terminal, rubocop

For some reason it takes a lot of time before it starts analyzing files.

```
$ date;rubocop -l;date;  
Mon Mar 13 12:19:53 -03 2023
Inspecting 182 files
......................................................................................................................................................................................

182 files inspected, no offenses detected
Mon Mar 13 12:20:26 -03 2023
```

I compared with other computers which are not using asdf, same thing. Other devs from the team have it running in under 5 seconds.

We also tried rubocop --server, which improved the time a bit but didn't quite fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

After some time investigating with the team we found out that while we were excluding some custom folders in our .rubocop.yml, it wasn't merging with default rubocop excluded folders, so it was analyzing .git, node_modules, tmp, etc.

The solution was to add this block to the top of your .rubocop.yml file

```
inherit_mode:
  merge:
    - Exclude
```

Then it scaled down from 35+ seconds to 2 second only.